# How to add IWebElement in Selenium to List<>() on C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am using Selenium to get all text from a table.

Tried filter values to reduce the list to easy manipulation. So, I do with this code:

```
IWebElement baseTable = browser.FindElementById("column2");
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> rowsInTable = baseTable.FindElements(By.XPath("id('oTableContainer_D')/table/tbody/tr"));

List<IWebElement> result;
foreach (IWebElement valuesNew in rowsInTable )
{
    if (valuesNew.FindElements(By.XPath("td")).ToString() == "")
        return;

    if (valuesNew.FindElements(By.XPath("td")).Count == 10)
    {
        result.Add(valuesNew.FindElements(By.XPath("td").ToString()));
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

#### Error is:

Because if I using:

`ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> result;`
This result does not have any method like `Add` to Add to a list.

Have any method to resolve this? Thanks, everybody.

UPDATED:

I'm want to get `result` variable because I get all item contains `<tr>`.

So, I changed to.

```
.....
result.Add(valuesNew).
.....
```

Comment: you might want to include the code line with `tableRowsDivTwoValues`

Comment: `tableRowsDivTwoValues ` is `rowsInTable`. I was updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is `AddRange` method of a `List`.

```
result.AddRange(valuesNew.FindElements(By.XPath("td")));
```

result is a `List<IWebElement>` and `FindElements` returns a collection, so you have to use `AddRange` method to add the collection.

On the side note, if you are in `ReadOnlycollection`, you could do this.

```
var  readOnlyelements = new ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>(result);
```

Comment: If using `AddRange` it create many items. I can't find this item in rows[n].

Like this. If using `Add` it will add `<td> include many text`, `AddRange` will add each text in <td> to a new items.

Comment: So you want to combine the text of each column (td) and add to list is it?

Comment: thanks so much. I updated my question. And it working. Thanks your answer.